# Stellar Explorer for Private Net

Tags: blockchain, stellar

I built and run Private net using a stellar-core on local infrastructure successfully. I need to connect that(**`http://localhost:8000/`**) local horizon API to the stellar explorer. I use this [link](https://github.com/chatch/stellarexplorer) to connect local horizon API to the explorer. I get an error when I set a Current Network on stellar-explorer which is running on **`http://localhost:5000/`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are the two approaches that worked for me. In the `server.js` file change the public net IP to point to your localhost IP. If that doesn't work, use ngrok on your localhost to create an HTTPS endpoint that then you can point the explorer to.